# Imaginary, holomorphic and bounded function, zero everywhere at $(i+n^\beta)$. Blaschke condition?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Is there a function $h\ne 0$, holomorphic and bounded on $\mathbb{H_+=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Im\,z > 0}\}$ zero exactly at at all points $(i+n^\beta)$, $0 \lt \beta \lt +\infty$, $n\gt 0$ ?

I have tried to use the Blashcke condition below.

Let $g=h \circ \phi$ where $\phi: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{H_+} $ with $\phi(z)=i\frac{1+z}{1-z}$.

Then $g$ is holomorphic and bounded on $\mathbb{D}$ and $h(i+n^\beta)=(g\circ \phi^{-1})(i+n^\beta)=0$, where $\phi^{-1}(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}:\mathbb{H_+}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$.

The function $h$ will be zero at all $(i+n^\beta)$ if $\sum_{n \gt 0} (1-|\phi^{-1}(i+n^\beta)|) \lt \infty$.

We have $|\phi^{-1}(i+n^\beta)|=\frac{n^\beta}{|2i+n^\beta|}=\frac{n^\beta}{\sqrt{n^{2\beta}+4}}$.

Also, $1-\frac{n^\beta}{\sqrt{n^{2\,\beta}+4}}=\frac{n^\beta \sqrt{1+4n^{-2\beta}}-n^\beta}{n^\beta\sqrt{1+4n^{-2\beta}}}\approx \frac{n^\beta (1+2n^{-2\beta})-n^\beta}{n^\beta(1+2n^{-2\beta})}=\frac{2n^{-2\beta}}{1+2n^{-2\beta}}\approx 2n^{-2\beta}$.

Hence, $\sum_{n \gt 0} (1-\frac{n^\beta}{\sqrt{n^{2\beta}+4}})$ satisfies the Blaschke condition if and only if $2\beta \gt 1$ i.e $\beta \gt \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: you mean all points $\in \ \{(i+n^\beta) \ \mid \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ ??

Comment: and [the Blaschke condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) requires that the series converge

Comment: @ user1952009 For all points  $\in \{(i+n^\beta) |\, n \in \mathbb{N}^* \}$.

Comment: $\sum_{n } (1-\frac{n^\beta}{\sqrt{n^{2\beta}+4}}) =\sum_{n } \frac{\sqrt{n^{2\beta}+4}- n^\beta}{\sqrt{n^{2\beta}+4}} = \sum_{n } \frac{\sqrt{1+4 n^{-2\beta}}- 1}{\sqrt{1+4 n^{-2\beta}}}$ then use the Taylor expansion of $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x}-1$ around $x=0$ to find an equivalent of  $\sqrt{1+4 n^{-2\beta}}- 1$

Comment: @ user1952009 For all points  $\in \{(i+n^\beta) |\, n \in \mathbb{N}^* \}$. Ok, so this would mean that such a function $h$ does not have any zero at points (\{(i+n^\beta)) and that $h=0$ ?

Comment: ?? what do you find for the series given what I wrote ?

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x}-1$ around $0$ is $x/2 +o(x^2)$, so $\sqrt{1+4 n^{-2\beta}}- 1$ $\approx 2n^{-2\beta}$ and $\sum_{n>0}{2n^{-2\beta}}$ converges for $\beta \gt 0$

Comment: for $\beta >0$ really ?

Comment: $\sum_{n>0}{\frac2{n^{2}}}$ converges to $\pi^2/3$ doesn't it ?

Comment: yes and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} \sim \int_1^\infty x^{-s} dx = \frac{1}{s-1}$ for $s > 1$, so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1}$ diverges

Comment: Agreed. But here we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ with $s=2\beta \gt 1$ for $\beta \gt 0$, which does converge (assuming $\beta \in \mathbb{N}$). Unless I missed something. I have assumed $\beta$ is an integer. If $\beta$ is not an integer, then we must have $\beta \geq 1$.

Comment: You already asked this question. And you didn't answer questions in the comments there, sort of rude really,  and then posted the same question again? Please don't do this again.

Comment: Rude? Did not answer questions? Sorry, I don't understand your reaction. I really did answer and did my best to understand the comments and what was wrong in my answers. For this problem, I indeed think I made a mistake regarding the convergence of the series but I still don't understand what is wrong with my answer in the comment. Anyway I will have another look at the problem later.